# Using QueryDSL to access properties in a type-safe manner

Tags: querydsl

I'm using QueryDSL in a project already and was wondering if I could (ab)use it to make my POJO-to-JSON conversion type-safe. Currently I do something like this:

> converter.toJson(entity, entity.getDetail(), "detail");

and I thought it would be cool if I could change it to this:

```
QEntity q = QEntity.entity;
converter.toJson(entity, q.detail);
```

and then, in the *toJson* method use the *q.detail* argument to extract the name of the property as well as call the getter on the entity to retrieve the value. It should be doable using *EntityPathBase.getType().getSimpleClassName()* and using reflection for the getter, but I'm wondering if that's something QueryDSL can do already.

**Outcome** I went with using *Path.getMetadata().getName()* which is available on query entities and returns the property name in the given sample. Combined with a *BeanMap* to retrieve the property values (as suggested by Timo, thanks!). And now I don't have to keep a getter call in sync with a string. Granted it's a tradeoff as reflection is now used, sacrificing some performance for better maintainability.

Comment: do you have the code of this converter shared in some place or you can share it with? I'm needing similar functionality in my project and would be great if I can get some insight on it. thanks! @jotomo

Comment: @avaz The code is rather specialized on the task at hand, so I'll give a quick summary of how it works in general. The converter uses Jackson to build a tree (using _ObjectMapper_'s _createObject_ and _createArrayNode_ methods) and uses the above _Path.getMetadata().getName()_ to build the name of a property. The method that does this is then simply passed a query entity, e.g. _addPropertyToNode(node, entity, q.address.streetname)_. HTH. (Source is closed, sorry).

Comment: thanks for the insight, I think I can follow this directions I reach something, regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that using the Querydsl Collections `GuavaHelpers` class http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.4/apidocs/com/mysema/query/collections/GuavaHelpers.html

Although I am not sure if the typesafety is needed in this case, since your target model (JSON) is not statically typed.

I'd probably just use a Bean helper class such as BeanMap for this case, if your use case is to copy bean properties to a JSON structure.